# char + int to change the char value

Tags: c++, char, ascii

I am new to C++, learned it for more than a month. I have a beginner-level knowledge of Python, like creating a list, modifying it, loops, etc. I don't know some codes for C++ that I know in python.

I am making a program for a school class (creative program). This is a part of my code (description at the bottom):

```cpp
int number, new_one, num_letter;
char one;

cout << "You chose to encypher a message\nPlease choose an integer between 1-25:";
cin >> number;

cout << "How many letters are in your word?";
cin >> num_letter;

if (num_letter == 1)
{
    cout << "Enter the first letter";
    cin >> one;

    new_one = one + number;

    cout << "Your encrypted message is '" 
         << static_cast<char>(new_one) 
         << "' with the code number of " 
         << number;
```

I am making a program where it enciphers and deciphers a message. The user chooses the number of letters of their message (maximum of 10 because I don't know how to use a `for`-loop in C++ yet). Then, they choose an integer. Then, they enter the letter, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, enter the letter, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> for the number of letters in their message (I don't know how to separate strings to chars in C++ yet).

When the user enters their letter and hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I `cin >>` that letter into the variable `one`, which is a `char`. Then, I add that `one` to the `number` the user chose, so the ASCII code of the `one` increases by the value of the `number`.

For example, when I enter `3` for `number` and `h` for the value of `one`, `104` (the ASCII code of `h`) should add up with `3`, resulting in `107`, which I then would `static_cast` to a `char` value.

But, when I add `h` and `3`, instead of creating `107`, it creates `155`. Same for other variables. I tried `cout`'ing `static_cast<int>(one)` (in this case, the letter `h`) and `number` (which is `3`). They printed `104`  and `3`.

But, when I add those two values, it prints `155`. Why is this happening?

Comment: [I can't replicate your problem](https://godbolt.org/z/r5ebEY7bv). Please [edit] your questions to show us a [mre]. And also tell us how you know that `new_one` becomes `155` instead of `107`. Also please copy-paste a full session running your minimal example, to show us the actual input and output.

Comment: @Jared Lee: This really looks like you should read up on C++ a little more first (Like how to do loops, for example). Here is a tutorial that i found really helpful: https://www.learncpp.com/

Comment: Are you using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). These are available as PDFs for free.

Comment: `155` is the sum of `104+51`. `104` is the ASCII code for the letter `'h'` and `51` is the ASCII code for the digit `'3'`. Which means you must be reading in your `number` as a `char` instead of as an `int`. But that is not what the code shown is doing, which means the code shown is not your real code that you are having trouble with.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you know how to let '3' stay as '3' when adding to 'h'? Thank you. --------Actually, I found out how. THanks

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. Hope it helps!

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int offset = 0;
    int num_with_offset;

    int size;
    
    // Gets offset from user
    do{
        cout << "You chose to encypher a message\nPlease choose an integer between 1-25: ";
        cin >> offset;
    } while (offset < 1 || offset > 25);
    
    // Gets letters in word
    do{
        cout << "Letters in word: ";
        cin >> size;
    } while(size < 0);
    
    // Given size, init arrays
    
    int number[size];
    char one[size];
    
    // Conversion from char to int
    for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(one)/sizeof(one[0])); i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter character " << (i + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> one[i];
        num_with_offset = one[i] + offset;
        // Converts ASCII to integer and stores it into array
        number[i] = static_cast<int>(num_with_offset);
    }
    
    // Prints out the new encrypted message
    for(int j = 0; j < (sizeof(number)/sizeof(number[0])); j++)
    {
        cout << "Your encrypted message is: "
             << number[j] << " , with the code number: "
             << offset << "." << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `nt number[size];` this is invalid in C++ and is just an extension in some compilers

Comment: I compiled with gcc in a unix environment. Didn't know it wasn't valid. Is there anything I could've done to fix what I did?

Comment: the keyword is [VLA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/995714). Replace with `std::vector` instead